# Try parse in sql server,unable to catch the error msg

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql server 2012

Here is the query:

```
begin try 
select try_parse(4 as xml) 
end try
begin catch
print 'in catch'
select ERROR_LINE()
select ERROR_MESSAGE()
select ERROR_SEVERITY()
end catch
```

I am try to cast int to xml,as it is a error operation but the same isn't detected in the catch block.

What is the mistake or error i am doing?

any help?

Comment: Seems like trying to use XML in TRY_PARSE() actually aborts the batch, so the error can't be handled cleanly using TRY/CATCH. This is probably because XML is not a valid data type for TRY_PARSE(): [`The values for the data_type parameter are restricted to the types shown in the following table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx).

Comment: Not only TRY_PARSE, Even TRY_CAST and TRY_CONVERT also aborts the batch why is that? @AaronBertrand

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand : what's up? thank you very much. I have read your blogs and seen the videos on youtube regarding sql tuning its good. thanks!

Comment: @NoDisplayName The parser works in mysterious ways. Note that this isn't caught by TRY / CATCH because it isn't a runtime error; it is a compile-time error. Throw a PRINT statement at the beginning to see this.

Comment: And it's the same reason `IF (1=1) CREATE TABLE #x() ELSE CREATE TABLE #x()` doesn't work and can't be caught. Parsing happens first.